# Issue with deploying Rasa bot on Teams via Azure Bot

Tags: python, botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service, rasa

I have developed a bot using the Rasa framework and Python, and I'm attempting to connect it with an Azure Bot I created. I've added the respective credentials in the credentials.yml file in Rasa as follows:

```
*botframework:
app_id: "my_app_id"
app_password: "my_app_password"*
```

I'm running the Rasa server locally using the command 'rasa run', and also the action server with 'rasa run actions'. I'm using ngrok to expose the webhook in the messaging endpoint configuration of the Azure bot like this:

```
https://ngrok_url_subdomain.ngrok-free.app/webhooks/botframework/webhook
```

Additionally, I've enabled the Teams platform in the channels. Previously, the bot worked correctly on Teams. However, now when I try to message it through the Teams desktop application or via the web page, I get the message "You can't send messages to this bot", so I can only access it from the Teams mobile application on my phone. I'm not sure if I missed any additional configuration or step.

Furthermore, I'm using Teams Cards in Python to display custom menus and some links. However, sometimes it doesn't show these messages created with Cards.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me clarify this issue.

Thank you.

I've attempted creating other bots in Azure and also deploying the Rasa bot and adding the URL to the Azure Bot endpoint, but the same issue persists.